# How to solve L6002U error in FreeRTOS

Tags: keil, freertos, stm32f4discovery

I am using STM32F4E11 Discovery board and Keil uVision 5.
Idea of project is that moisture sensor is giving data. Water pump(DC 12 V motor) and two seven segment display with two shifts receiving data. Display shows moisture percentage and pump is working with pwm according to received data.

When i compile my code it shows me :
Završni_2\Završni_2.axf: error: L6002U: Could not open file zavr?ni_2\event_groups.o: No such file or directory

Here is my code.Please help me.

```html
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"
#include "stm32f4xx_hal.h"
#include "cmsis_os.h"

/*Defines(shift register)---------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

/*Latch on*/
#define STCP_RESET  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_9, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
/*Latch off*/
#define STCP_SET    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_9, GPIO_PIN_SET);
/*Clock on*/
#define SHCP_RESET  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_10, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
/*Clock off*/
#define SHCP_SET    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_10, GPIO_PIN_SET);
/*No data*/
#define DS_RESET    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_11, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
/*Data in*/
#define DS_SET      HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_11, GPIO_PIN_SET);

/*Defines(display digits)---------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

/*First difit off*/
#define ONE_RESET   HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_8, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
/*First digit on*/
#define ONE_SET     HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_8, GPIO_PIN_SET);
/*Second digit on*/
#define TWO_RESET   HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_15, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
/*Second digit off*/
#define TWO_SET     HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_15, GPIO_PIN_SET);

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
ADC_HandleTypeDef hadc1;
TIM_HandleTypeDef htim2;
TIM_HandleTypeDef htim4;

osThreadId ONHandle;
osThreadId OFFHandle;
osThreadId VlagaHandle;
osThreadId PumpaHandle;
osThreadId DisplayHandle;
osThreadId SEMHandle;
QueueHandle_t xQueue;
SemaphoreHandle_t xBinarySemaphore;
long VLA=0;

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_TIM4_Init(void);
static void MX_TIM2_Init(void);
static void MX_ADC1_Init(void);
void StartON(void const * argument);
void StartOFF(void const * argument);
void StartVlaga(void const * argument);
void StartPumpa(void const * argument);
void SegOFF(void);
void DigitDisplay(long);
void StartDisplay(void const * argument);
void StartSEM(void const * argument);



int main(void)
{
  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_TIM4_Init();
  MX_TIM2_Init();
  MX_ADC1_Init();

 /* definition and creation of tasks */
 
 osThreadDef(ON, StartON, osPriorityRealtime, 0, 128);
  ONHandle = osThreadCreate(osThread(ON), NULL);
 
 osThreadDef(OFF, StartOFF, osPriorityRealtime, 0, 128);
  OFFHandle = osThreadCreate(osThread(OFF), NULL);
  
 osThreadDef(Vlaga, StartVlaga, osPriorityRealtime, 0, 128);
  VlagaHandle = osThreadCreate(osThread(Vlaga), NULL);
 
 osThreadDef(Pumpa, StartPumpa, osPriorityRealtime, 0, 128);
  PumpaHandle = osThreadCreate(osThread(Pumpa), NULL);

  osThreadDef(Display, StartDisplay, osPriorityRealtime, 0, 128);
  DisplayHandle = osThreadCreate(osThread(Display), NULL);
 
 osThreadDef(SEM, StartSEM, osPriorityRealtime, 0, 128);
  SEMHandle = osThreadCreate(osThread(SEM), NULL);
 
 /*Suspending tasks*/
 vTaskSuspend(ONHandle);
 vTaskSuspend(VlagaHandle);
 vTaskSuspend(PumpaHandle);
 vTaskSuspend(DisplayHandle);
  
 /*definition and creation of Queue*/
 xQueue=xQueueCreate(1,sizeof(long));
 
 /*definition and creation of Binary Semaphore*/
 xBinarySemaphore=xSemaphoreCreateBinary();
  
 /* Start scheduler */
  osKernelStart();
  
  /* We should never get here as control is now taken by the scheduler */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
  }
}

/* StartON function */
void StartON(void const * argument)
{
for(;;)
   { 
     /*Blinking green led as indicator that system is ON*/
     HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOD,GPIO_PIN_12);
     osDelay(250);
   }
 
}

/* StartOFF function */
void StartOFF(void const * argument)
{
/*Infinite loop*/ 
for(;;)
   {  
   /*Blinking red led as indicator that system is OFF*/
     HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOD,GPIO_PIN_14);
   }
 } 
/* StartDisplay function */
void StartDisplay(void const * argument)
{
 
long rx=0;
short flag=0;
 
for(;;){
    
     /*Receiving data from a queue*/
    if(xQueueReceive(xQueue,&rx,10)){   
   SegOFF();
   osDelay(400);
   flag=1;
       }
    
       long   ones=rx%10; 
       long   tens=(rx%100)/10; 
       
if(flag) {
      /*Displaying first digit*/
       ONE_RESET;TWO_SET;
       DigitDisplay(ones);
      
      /*Displaying second digit*/
       ONE_SET;TWO_RESET;
       DigitDisplay(tens);
       
      
          }
      }
}
  
  /* StartVlaga function*/
void StartVlaga(void const * argument)
{    
    
     /* Infinite loop */
     for(;;){
           
      HAL_ADC_Start(&hadc1);
    HAL_ADC_PollForConversion(&hadc1,1000);
    VLA=HAL_ADC_GetValue(&hadc1);
           VLA=(VLA/4091)*100;
      xQueueSendToBack(xQueue,&VLA,10);
          
              /*Resuming tasks*/    
            vTaskResume(DisplayHandle);
           vTaskResume(PumpaHandle);
           vTaskSuspend(NULL);
           osDelay(2000);
   }

}/*StartPumpa function*/
void StartPumpa(void const * argument){
    
 long Value=0;
      /* Infinite loop */
      for(;;){
         
           /*Reciving vlaga to a queue*/
       xQueueReceive(xQueue,&Value,10);
      
    HAL_TIM_PWM_Start(&htim4,TIM_CHANNEL_1);
    
    if(Value<25)
    {htim4.Instance->CCR1=75;
    }
    if (Value<50)
    {htim4.Instance->CCR1=50;
    }
       if(Value<75)
    {htim4.Instance->CCR1=25;
    }
    
           vTaskResume(VlagaHandle);
           vTaskSuspend(NULL);
    }
}
  
  /* StartSEM function */
void StartSEM(void const * argument)
{
 short button=0;
 /*Infinite loop*/
 
 for(;;){
        /*Checking if interrupt occured*/
          if(xSemaphoreTake(xBinarySemaphore,  portMAX_DELAY )) {
          button++;
          if (button==1){
                    /*If  button is pressed only pump is working on 50 % */
                
                          osDelay(2000);
                          vTaskSuspend(VlagaHandle);
                          vTaskSuspend(PumpaHandle);
                       vTaskSuspend(DisplayHandle);
                          SegOFF();
                          vTaskSuspend(ONHandle);
                   HAL_TIM_PWM_Start(&htim4,TIM_CHANNEL_1);
                      htim4.Instance->CCR1=50;
                          HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD,GPIO_PIN_12,GPIO_PIN_RESET);
                          vTaskResume(OFFHandle);
                       }
       
          else if(button==2){
                          /*when button is pressed second time its start all again*/
                           vTaskSuspend(OFFHandle);
                          HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD,GPIO_PIN_14,GPIO_PIN_RESET);
                          vTaskResume(ONHandle);
                       vTaskResume(VlagaHandle);
                          button=0;
                           }
        }
     }
}
  
  /*This function handles EXTI line0 interrupt*/
void EXTI0_IRQHandler(void)
{
  for(uint32_t z=0;z<10000000;z++);
 xSemaphoreGiveFromISR(xBinarySemaphore, NULL);
  HAL_GPIO_EXTI_IRQHandler(GPIO_PIN_0);
  
}
  
/*Function for putting data in shift register*/
void DigitDisplay(long digit)
{
  short i=0;
  long field[8][10]=   {{1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
                         {1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1},
             {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1},
             {0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1},
             {1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
             {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
             {1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1},
                  {1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0} };       
            
  
 
  /*Latch off*/  
 STCP_RESET;
 
 for(i=0;i<8;i++){
    /*Clock off*/
     SHCP_RESET;
  
      if(field[i][digit] ){
        /*Shifting 1*/
         DS_SET;
             }
      else{
            /*Shifting 0*/     
          DS_RESET;
       }  
     /*Clock on*/
          SHCP_SET;
} 
      /*Latch on*/ 
     STCP_SET;
      
    /*Delay*/
   osDelay(1);
}

void SegOFF(void)
{
 
 ONE_SET;TWO_SET;
  long x=0;
 /*Latch off*/
 STCP_RESET;
 for(x=0;x<8;x++){
    /*Clock off*/
     SHCP_RESET    
    /*Shifting 0*/
          DS_RESET;
         
     /*Clock on*/
          SHCP_SET;
} 
      /*Latch on*/ 
     STCP_SET;

}

/** System Clock Configuration
*/
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{

  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct;
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct;

    /**Configure the main internal regulator output voltage 
    */
  __HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_ENABLE();

  __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1);

    /**Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks 
    */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = 16;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLM = 8;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLN = 84;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLP = RCC_PLLP_DIV2;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLQ = 8;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

    /**Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks 
    */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

    /**Configure the Systick interrupt time 
    */
  HAL_SYSTICK_Config(HAL_RCC_GetHCLKFreq()/1000);

    /**Configure the Systick 
    */
  HAL_SYSTICK_CLKSourceConfig(SYSTICK_CLKSOURCE_HCLK);

  /* SysTick_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(SysTick_IRQn, 15, 0);
}

/* ADC1 init function */
static void MX_ADC1_Init(void)
{

  ADC_ChannelConfTypeDef sConfig;

    /**Configure the global features of the ADC (Clock, Resolution, Data Alignment and number of conversion) 
    */
  hadc1.Instance = ADC1;
  hadc1.Init.ClockPrescaler = ADC_CLOCK_SYNC_PCLK_DIV4;
  hadc1.Init.Resolution = ADC_RESOLUTION_12B;
  hadc1.Init.ScanConvMode = DISABLE;
  hadc1.Init.ContinuousConvMode = ENABLE;
  hadc1.Init.DiscontinuousConvMode = DISABLE;
  hadc1.Init.ExternalTrigConvEdge = ADC_EXTERNALTRIGCONVEDGE_NONE;
  hadc1.Init.ExternalTrigConv = ADC_SOFTWARE_START;
  hadc1.Init.DataAlign = ADC_DATAALIGN_RIGHT;
  hadc1.Init.NbrOfConversion = 1;
  hadc1.Init.DMAContinuousRequests = DISABLE;
  hadc1.Init.EOCSelection = ADC_EOC_SINGLE_CONV;
  if (HAL_ADC_Init(&hadc1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

    /**Configure for the selected ADC regular channel its corresponding rank in the sequencer and its sample time. 
    */
  sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_1;
  sConfig.Rank = 1;
  sConfig.SamplingTime = ADC_SAMPLETIME_480CYCLES;
  if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

}

/* TIM2 init function */
static void MX_TIM2_Init(void)
{

  TIM_ClockConfigTypeDef sClockSourceConfig;
  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig;

  htim2.Instance = TIM2;
  htim2.Init.Prescaler = 0;
  htim2.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim2.Init.Period = 0;
  htim2.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

  sClockSourceConfig.ClockSource = TIM_CLOCKSOURCE_INTERNAL;
  if (HAL_TIM_ConfigClockSource(&htim2, &sClockSourceConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim2, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

}

/* TIM4 init function */
static void MX_TIM4_Init(void)
{

  TIM_ClockConfigTypeDef sClockSourceConfig;
  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig;
  TIM_OC_InitTypeDef sConfigOC;

  htim4.Instance = TIM4;
  htim4.Init.Prescaler = 83;
  htim4.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim4.Init.Period = 99;
  htim4.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim4) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

  sClockSourceConfig.ClockSource = TIM_CLOCKSOURCE_INTERNAL;
  if (HAL_TIM_ConfigClockSource(&htim4, &sClockSourceConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

  if (HAL_TIM_PWM_Init(&htim4) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim4, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

  sConfigOC.OCMode = TIM_OCMODE_PWM1;
  sConfigOC.Pulse = 0;
  sConfigOC.OCPolarity = TIM_OCPOLARITY_HIGH;
  sConfigOC.OCFastMode = TIM_OCFAST_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_PWM_ConfigChannel(&htim4, &sConfigOC, TIM_CHANNEL_1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

  HAL_TIM_MspPostInit(&htim4);

}

/** Configure pins as 
        * Analog 
        * Input 
        * Output
        * EVENT_OUT
        * EXTI
*/
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{

  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOH_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOD_CLK_ENABLE();

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_14|GPIO_PIN_15, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_8|GPIO_PIN_9|GPIO_PIN_10|GPIO_PIN_11, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : PC13 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_13;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_INPUT;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pin : PA0 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_0;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_IT_RISING;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : PB14 PB15 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_14|GPIO_PIN_15;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : PD8 PD9 PD10 PD11 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_8|GPIO_PIN_9|GPIO_PIN_10|GPIO_PIN_11;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOD, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  /* EXTI interrupt init*/
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(EXTI0_IRQn, 5, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(EXTI0_IRQn);

}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */

/* USER CODE END 4 */

/* StartDefaultTask function */
void StartDefaultTask(void const * argument)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN 5 */
  /* Infinite loop */
  for(;;)
  {
    osDelay(1);
  }
  /* USER CODE END 5 */ 
}

/**
  * @brief  Period elapsed callback in non blocking mode
  * @note   This function is called  when TIM1 interrupt took place, inside
  * HAL_TIM_IRQHandler(). It makes a direct call to HAL_IncTick() to increment
  * a global variable "uwTick" used as application time base.
  * @param  htim : TIM handle
  * @retval None
  */
void HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim)
{
/* USER CODE BEGIN Callback 0 */

/* USER CODE END Callback 0 */
  if (htim->Instance == TIM1) {
    HAL_IncTick();
  }
/* USER CODE BEGIN Callback 1 */

/* USER CODE END Callback 1 */
}

/**
  * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
  * @param  None
  * @retval None
  */
void _Error_Handler(char * file, int line)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */
  while(1) 
  {
  }
  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */ 
}

#ifdef USE_FULL_ASSERT

/**
   * @brief Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
   * where the assert_param error has occurred.
   * @param file: pointer to the source file name
   * @param line: assert_param error line source number
   * @retval None
   */
void assert_failed(uint8_t* file, uint32_t line)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
    ex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
  /* USER CODE END 6 */

}

#endif

/**
  * @}
  */ 

/**
  * @}
*/ 

/************************ (C) COPYRIGHT STMicroelectronics *****END OF FILE****/
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the compiler doesn't like the special characters. Try to store the project and all of its files in a path that only contains Latin characters (and no spaces, to be sure).